# PHP 413 (Request Entity Too Large)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, xml

When I'm trying to transfer a XML file to server I get this error.

In my scenario a web page processes a XML file with javascript and then upload the XML processed file to a PHP server.

The file capacity is 400K.

**php.ini**

```
post_max_size = 8M
upload_max_filesize = 2M
memory_limit = 128M
```

**Client initial request:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/dirname/filename.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    async: false,
    success: function(data){
        xmlCID = data;
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log(jqXHR.responseText, textStatus, errorThrown);
        alert(textStatus);
    }
});
```

**Client upload request**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/dirname/filename.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    method: "PUT",
    processData: false,
    data: xmlCID,
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
       alert(jqXHR.responseText, textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Unfortunely, server response is:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>413 - Request Entity Too Large</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>413 - Request Entity Too Large</h1>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Since it's 40 minutes after you asked the question and there are no takers, I'm gonna ask a (perhaps) stupid question. Did you restart the web server after modifying php.ini? Check with phpinfo().

Comment: Yes, sure. I've just checked by phpinfo().

Comment: The error message most likely is from your *web-server* (not PHP). That means you have to check the error-log of your web-server and see what is causing the issue. You should find it in there with a more specific technical description what caused the error.

Comment: Yes, problem was into webserver config file. I use lighttpd and upload directory was missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As hakre pointed out, beyond the settings in PHP you'll often receive 413 errors occur when the size of the request payload is beyond what the *web server* configuration allows. These directives vary by server, but here are some common ones (if you're using a hosted platform, you'll likely need to contact your host's support team):

- **Nginx**: Look at the `client_max_body_size` directive for `nginx.conf` (http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size)
- **Apache**: The directive `LimitRequestBody` can be used in `httpd.conf` or in directory-level `.htaccess` files (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody)
- **IIS**: Look into `maxAllowedContentLength` (part of `requestFiltering` > `requestLimits`), or `UploadReadAheadSize` in IIS6 (IIS solutions are very version-dependent, so I'd recommend researching a bit).

If you're serving requests over HTTP and HTTPS, make sure that the relevant configuration applies to both.

While less common (more so in corporate networks), this can also have to do with other proxies or security devices that the request is being passed through, since each of those may have different limits affecting the handling of the request.

When in doubt, check the logs: first, make sure that the request is getting to your server (in the access logs), if it is, check the response code, and then also check the error logs.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes, problem was into webserver config file. I use lighttpd and upload directory was missing.

Comment: Glad you tracked it down, gravi! I've never seen a 413 for that type of issue, but I'll have to remember that when working with lighthttpd in the future.